# Linearization of 1D maps about a fixed unstable point

Tags: non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems, linearized-theory

Recently, I was going through the paper [**Controlling Chemical Chaos**](https://doi.org/10.1021/j100166a013) in a three variable autocatalator system, by Peng et al. Here are the references

[image]

[image]

Although I have been introduced to 1D maps and the logistic map as well, but a certain point has been bugging me for some time.

[image]

In the above picture, I don't seem to understand how are they trying to linearize the map in the way mentioned, and I even don't know the dependence of $s$ on $k$ or $n$. If $\beta _{n+1}$ is some function of $\beta _{n}$, then it can be expanded about the fixed unstable point for small perturbations. But how do they arrive at the above mentioned stage, I'm totally unaware of. Can someone help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple Taylor expansion, but their notation maybe is not great.

When they write $f(\beta_n -\beta_s)$ it might look like $f$ is a function and $\beta_n -\beta_s$ its argument, when actually $f$ is essentially a constant number that is multiplying $\Delta\beta=\beta_n -\beta_s$, which is the distance from the $k$-periodic point at $\beta_s$.

This follows directly from the [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) truncated to the linear term:

$$g(x) \approx g(a) + g'(a)\cdot(x-a),$$

with

$$x\to \beta_n, \quad g(x)\to \beta_{n+k}, \quad g(a)=a\to \beta_s, \quad g'(a)\to f,$$

resulting in their expression

$$\beta_{n+k} = \beta_s + f\cdot(\beta_n -\beta_s).$$

As the page you've included explains:

> $f$ is the slope of the map at $\beta_s$, the position of the unstable point

which means that $\beta_s$ and $f$ implicitly depend on $k$ — after all, the curve on the return plot (Fig. 2 of OP) in general depends on it being the 1st, the 2nd or the $k$-th return.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I was able to work that out after thinking on it for some more time!